# How do I create a logout route in symfony?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to implement a simple login and logout in my symfony app and in the documentation it says I need to create a route to the logout page. And there is a code like this:

```
# app/config/routing.yml
logout:
   path: /logout
```

I'm trying to paste it into my app/config/routing.yml, so it looks like this:

```
# app/config/routing.yml
app:
    resource: '@AppBundle/Controller/'
    type:     annotation
logout:
    path: /logout
```

But I get an error

```
The file "(...)\app/config\routing.yml" does not contain valid YAML
```

I was searching through the documentation and couldn't find anythig that would help me solve it. I can't really understand how this routing configuration file works and why I get this error.

Comment: check routing.yml layout, there is something with it, so it's content not valid YAML

Comment: My awesome mental powers tell me that you have three spaces in front of path instead of four.  That will be $500 please.

Comment: I had a tab there. But changing it to four spaces actually did help. Seriously, that is some strange syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest when making changes to any yaml file in a development environment, save the yaml first, make the change, then check for error messages. If you get error messages back them out.

Also set up your editor so that it points out things like tabs, spaces, etc... So it's easier to see right away.